# How to use two condition in mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a sql query where result can be 0 or 1.

Here is what I've got.
I know below php code is wrong but i want to make it work like that.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1 OR $check == 0){
```

Is there something in php which make my above line correct or true?

Comment: Why you are using mysqli_num_rows() for the first time and not using the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mysqli_num_rows($check) in both cases:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1 || mysqli_num_rows($check) == 0){
```

OR

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) >= 0){
```

Comment: || is giving error Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in

Comment: @justbaron, FYI, whoever told you that about OR just have no clue.

Comment: @YourCommonSense agreed. My mistake.

Comment: Since the number of rows can never be negative, why not just do `mysqli_num_rows($check) <= 1`, less or equal to 1?